# EASELJS: dotted lines appearing just above my bitmaps

Tags: html, image, easeljs, createjs

Game Screenshot
http://www.image-share.com/ipng-2442-264.html

Hey, i'm a making a html5 game and on these particular star bitmaps I have the tiny dotted lines appearing. I've checked my png images and they dont have any dots on them.
Anyone with ideas about this issue?

Comment: This is probably an issue with the transparent PNG and the browser. You should try exporting your images with 1px of padding around the edges.

Comment: Thanks mate! That seemed to have improved it albeit slightly